# Routes in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Does anybody know if the IgnoreRoute() directives fire on the 1st matched rule like Apache directives or do they act differently?

I would like to route my elmah.axd to a different location than my other .axd files so I created 2 IgnoreRoute rules in which the 1st rule will catch elmah.axd and the second rule will catch all other .axd files.

Here is what I have:

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        // AXD files
        routes.IgnoreRoute("AdminTools/elmah.axd/{*pathinfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //Everything else
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.txt");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [article on Three common ASP.NET MVC URL routing issues](http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/09/three-common-aspnet-mvc-url-routing-issues/)

> you need to add them [the routes] in the order of most to least
>   specific